# the div doesn't come back to its place when the div the window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

the div moves without problem below 768, but when I resize above it does not return to its original place.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function(){
   if ( $(window).width() < 768) {
        $('#div_block-61-89').detach().prependTo('.offcanvas-inner');
    };
    });
});
```

any help please

Comment: You code doesn't store original position, nor it does anything when window is above 768.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is store original position of the element before it's moved and than restore it to that position if window size is less than 768

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    const div = $('#div_block-61-89');
    const domPos = div.data("domPos");

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      if (!domPos) //store position
        div.data("domPos", {el: div.next()||div.parent(), func: div.next() ? "before" :"append"});

      div.prependTo('.offcanvas-inner');
    }
    else if (domPos) //less than 768
    {
      //restore position
      domPos.el[domPos.func](div);
      //remove stored position 
      div.data("domPos", null);
    }
  }).trigger("resize");//check resize on startup
});
```

Comment: sorry but the probleme is still there (https://yomaroc.com/fr/product/vol-montgolfiere-marrakech/)

Comment: it works just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/f3n678g5/
Sorry, I don't know what you did wrong there.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but unfortunately in my case does not work, I use oxygen builder of wordpress and this is the first time I have difficulty finding a solution for a problem,